# regular expressions in python using quotes

Tags: python, regex

I am attempting to create a regular expression pattern for strings similar to the below which are stored in a file. The aim is to get any column for any row, the rows need not be on a single line. So for example, consider the following file:

```
"column1a","column2a","column
  3a,",             #entity 1
"column\"this is, a test\"4a"
"column1b","colu
     mn2b,","column3b",             #entity 2
"column\"this is, a test\"4b"
"column1c,","column2c","column3c",             #entity 3
"column\"this is, a test\"4c"
```

Each entity consists of four columns, column 4 for entity 2 would be "column\"this is, a test\"4b", column 2 for entity 3 would be "column2c". Each column begins with a quote and closes with a quote, however you must be careful because some columns have escaped quotes. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What have you attempted so far?

Comment: I am lost with the regular expression, I have no idea where to start with such a problem. the code around it should not be an issue

Comment: What's wrong with the standard CSV reader library? IIRC it supports this variant bastard dialect of CSV just fine with the right options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is terribly familiar to what I have to deal thrice every month :) Except I'm not using python to solve it, but I can 'translate' what I usually do:

```
text = r'''"column1a","column2a","column
  3a,",
"column\"this is, a test\"4a"
"column1a2","column2a2","column3a2","column4a2"
"column1b","colu
     mn2b,","column3b",             
"column\"this is, a test\"4b"
"column1c,","column2c","column3c",
"column\"this is, a test\"4c"'''

import re

# Number of columns one line is supposed to have
columns = 4
# Temporary variable to hold partial lines
buffer = ""
# Our regex to check for each column
check = re.compile(r'"(?:[^"\\]*|\\.)*"')

# Read the file line by line
for line in text.split("\n"):
    # If there's no stored partial line, this is a new line
    if buffer == "":
        # Check if we get 4 columns and print, if not, put the line
        # into buffer so we store a partial line for later
        if len(check.findall(line)) == columns:
            print matches
        else:
            # use line.strip() if you need to trim whitespaces
            buffer = line
    else:
        # Update the variable (containing a partial line) with the
        # next line and recheck if we get 4 columns
        # use line.strip() if you need to trim whitespaces
        buffer = buffer + line
        # If we indeed get 4, our line is complete and print
        # We must not forget to empty buffer now that we got a whole line
        if len(check.findall(buffer)) == columns:
            print matches
            buffer = ""
        # Optional; always good to have a safety backdoor though
        # If there is a problem with the csv itself like a weird unescaped
        # quote, you send it somewhere else
        elif len(check.findall(buffer)) > columns:
            print "Error: cannot parse line:\n" + buffer
            buffer = ""
```

[ideone demo](http://ideone.com/znH27i)

Comment: Note: the above works even if one entity (the 4 columns) were split onto several hundreds of lines if that happened.

Comment: thanks Jerry, it looks good however I am seeing this error  when i try running: raise error, v # invalid expression

Comment: which version of python are you using?

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 16, in <module>
    check = re.compile(r'"(?:[^"\\]*|\\.)+"')
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/re.py", line 190, in compile
    return _compile(pattern, flags)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/re.py", line 242, in _compile
    raise error, v # invalid expression
sre_constants.error: nothing to repeat

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by character class, but my re version is also 2.2.1

Comment: agh it might not be handling the \\ properly, i only see one in the error message

Comment: nope error message has 2 backslashes, just checked, stack overflow probably has issues with me pasting it here

Comment: @godzilla I'm out of ideas... last try: try this expression instead: `r'"(?:[^"\\]+|\\.)+"'`

Comment: @godzilla Hmm, I just thought of something. It might actually be better with `r'"(?:[^"\\]+|\\.)*"'`.

Comment: Jerry sorry I get occasions where the regex eats more strings than it should and hits the "can not parse line" condition, can we have a quick discussion via chat?

Comment: I have noticed there are some strings with \' that need handling by the regex for example toyota\'s or John\'s which is causing an issue

Comment: i have just hacked the code to do the following replace the \' with just ' but it's not ideal, it would be better to just have the regex handle it

Answer (score 2):

You could do like this, ie

1. Read the whole file.
2. Split the input according to the newline character which was not preceded by a comma.
3. Iterate over the spitted elements  and again do splitting on the comma (*and also the following optional newline character*) which was preceded and followed by double quotes.

Code:

```
import re
with open(file) as f:
    fil = f.read()
    m = re.split(r'(?<!,)\n', fil.strip())
    for i in m:
        print(re.split('(?<="),\n?(?=")', i))
```

Output:

```
['"column1a"', '"column2a"', '"column3a,"', '"column\\"this is, a test\\"4a"']
['"column1b"', '"column2b,"', '"column3b"', '"column\\"this is, a test\\"4b"']
['"column1c,"', '"column2c"', '"column3c"', '"column\\"this is, a test\\"4c"']
```

Here is the check..

```
$ cat f
"column1a","column2a","column3a,",
"column\"this is, a test\"4a"
"column1b","column2b,","column3b",
"column\"this is, a test\"4b"
"column1c,","column2c","column3c",
"column\"this is, a test\"4c"
$ python3 f.py
['"column1a"', '"column2a"', '"column3a,"', '"column\\"this is, a test\\"4a"']
['"column1b"', '"column2b,"', '"column3b"', '"column\\"this is, a test\\"4b"']
['"column1c,"', '"column2c"', '"column3c"', '"column\\"this is, a test\\"4c"']
```

`f` is the input file name and `f.py` is the file-name which contains the python script.

Comment: thanks Avinash, just one issue - what if one one the entities covered multiple lines? Can we factor that in as well?

Comment: so rather than newline you're looking for quotes